# Daily updates to page in phone gap android app

Tags: android, cordova

I am using phone gap to program an android app and I want one page on the app that is updated daily with news and information.

I have a few ideas and have tried a few solutions mainly just linking to a website where I am hosting a page that I update.

Does anyone have any better, more built-in solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered an RSS feed (or several)? There are plenty of examples of basic RSS readers in Phonegap. This one, http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/10/11/PhoneGap-RSS-Reader could be a good start.

Comment: that is a good idea although I may just require internet access for this section and have it link to a mobile customized internet page.

Comment: Test for Internet connectivity. Download the feed of the day, and you're good to go.